# How to retrieve Envelope Location and Holder using DocuSign Rest API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to recreate the document history that you can see in the DocuSign user interface [History from web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbsmV.png).

I have been able to retrieve almost all of the data using the rest API but I cannot find the envelope **Location** or **Holder** anywhere.

Can anyone tell me how I might retrieve these using the Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

**Using C#**, If you have both EnvelopesApi and EnvelopeSummary information of the document that you are trying to retrieve, you can use below code.

```
public static void GetDocument(EnvelopesApi envelopesApi, EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary)
{
    var doc = envelopesApi.GetDocument(_accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, "1");
    using (var fileStream = File.Create((@"Path")))
    {
        doc.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        doc.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```